# IP Camera 401 unauthorized Error

Tags: c#-4.0

While connecting IP camera with C# app, i found the simple player in Aforge/Samples/Player. It just needed modifying the ip string so i added mine *admin:admin@192.168.1.239:81/videostream.cgi?rate=11* to get MJPEG video stream. On compiling i get error as
The Remote server returned an Error (401) Unauthorized. 
Andre Kirillow mentioned in MJPEGstream.cs file 
Some cameras produce HTTP header, which does not conform strictly to standard, what leads to .NET exception. To avoid this exception the **useUnsafeHeaderParsing** configuration option of **httpWebRequest** should be set, what may be done using application configuration file.

```
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <settings>
            <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
        </settings>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

well there are two ways to do this as suggested by [Dinis Cruz](http://o2platform.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/dealing-with-the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-sectionresponsestatusline/). I added the .config file wth the above code and also did it programmaticaly but same error persists. The Player program coding is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;

using System.Reflection;
using System.Net.Configuration;
using System.Net;

namespace Player
{
  public partial class MainForm : Form
   {
    private Stopwatch stopWatch = null;

    // Class constructor
    public MainForm( ) 
    {
        InitializeComponent( );
    }

    private void MainForm_FormClosing( object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e )
    {
        CloseCurrentVideoSource( );
    }

    // "Exit" menu item clicked
    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        this.Close( );
    }

    // Open local video capture device
    private void localVideoCaptureDeviceToolStripMenuItem_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        VideoCaptureDeviceForm form = new VideoCaptureDeviceForm( );

        if ( form.ShowDialog( this ) == DialogResult.OK )
        {
            // create video source
            VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = form.VideoDevice;

            // open it
            OpenVideoSource( videoSource );
        }
    }

    // Open video file using DirectShow
    private void openVideofileusingDirectShowToolStripMenuItem_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        if ( openFileDialog.ShowDialog( ) == DialogResult.OK )
        {
            // create video source
            FileVideoSource fileSource = new FileVideoSource( openFileDialog.FileName );

            // open it
            OpenVideoSource( fileSource );
        }
    }

    // Open JPEG URL
    private void openJPEGURLToolStripMenuItem_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        URLForm form = new URLForm( );

        form.Description = "Enter URL of an updating JPEG from a web camera:";
        form.URLs = new string[]
            {
                "http://195.243.185.195/axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi?camera=1",
            };

        if ( form.ShowDialog( this ) == DialogResult.OK )
        {
            // create video source
            JPEGStream jpegSource = new JPEGStream( form.URL );

            // open it
            OpenVideoSource( jpegSource );
        }
    }

    // Open MJPEG URL
    private void openMJPEGURLToolStripMenuItem_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        URLForm form = new URLForm( );

        form.Description = "Enter URL of an MJPEG video stream:";
        form.URLs = new string[]
            {
                "http://admin@192.168.1.239:81/videostream.cgi?rate=11",
                "mjpegSource by mobby"
            };

        if ( form.ShowDialog( this ) == DialogResult.OK )
        {
            // create video source
            MJPEGStream mjpegSource = new MJPEGStream( form.URL );

            // open it
            OpenVideoSource( mjpegSource );
        }
    }

    // Open video source
    private void OpenVideoSource( IVideoSource source )
    {
        // set busy cursor
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        // stop current video source
        //CloseCurrentVideoSource( );

        // start new video source
        videoSourcePlayer.VideoSource = source;
        videoSourcePlayer.Start( );

        // reset stop watch
        stopWatch = null;

        // start timer
        timer.Start( );

        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }

    // Close video source if it is running
    private void CloseCurrentVideoSource( )
    {
        if ( videoSourcePlayer.VideoSource != null )
        {
            videoSourcePlayer.SignalToStop( );

            // wait ~ 3 seconds
            for ( int i = 0; i < 30; i++ )
            {
                if ( !videoSourcePlayer.IsRunning )
                    break;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep( 100 );
            }

            if ( videoSourcePlayer.IsRunning )
            {
                videoSourcePlayer.Stop( );
            }

            videoSourcePlayer.VideoSource = null;
        }
    }

    // New frame received by the player
    private void videoSourcePlayer_NewFrame( object sender, ref Bitmap image )
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage( image );

        // paint current time
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush( Color.Red );
        g.DrawString( now.ToString( ), this.Font, brush, new PointF( 5, 5 ) );
        brush.Dispose( );

        g.Dispose( );
    }

    // On timer event - gather statistics
    private void timer_Tick( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        IVideoSource videoSource = videoSourcePlayer.VideoSource;

        if ( videoSource != null )
        {
            // get number of frames since the last timer tick
            int framesReceived = videoSource.FramesReceived;

            if ( stopWatch == null )
            {
                stopWatch = new Stopwatch( );
                stopWatch.Start( );
            }
            else
            {
                stopWatch.Stop( );

                float fps = 1000.0f * framesReceived / stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                fpsLabel.Text = fps.ToString( "F2" ) + " fps";

                stopWatch.Reset( );
                stopWatch.Start( );
            }
        }
    }

    public static bool SetAllowUnsafeHeaderParsing20()
    {
        //Get the assembly that contains the internal class
        Assembly aNetAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSection));
        if (aNetAssembly != null)
        {
            //Use the assembly in order to get the internal type for the internal class
            Type aSettingsType = aNetAssembly.GetType("System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSectionInternal");
            if (aSettingsType != null)
            {
                //Use the internal static property to get an instance of the internal settings class.
                //If the static instance isn't created allready the property will create it for us.
                object anInstance = aSettingsType.InvokeMember("Section",
                BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, null, new object[] { });
                if (anInstance != null)
                {
                    //Locate the private bool field that tells the framework is unsafe header parsing should be allowed or not
                    FieldInfo aUseUnsafeHeaderParsing = aSettingsType.GetField("useUnsafeHeaderParsing", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    if (aUseUnsafeHeaderParsing != null)
                    {
                        aUseUnsafeHeaderParsing.SetValue(anInstance, true);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

From google i added some open ip cameras and there video stream was captured and worked fine but my camera returns Error 401. Then I used ISPY software recently made by [Sean Tearney](http://www.ispyconnect.com/) that was built using the same Aforge library and it captures my camera's video stream:p. Now i do not know what's wrong with the simple player's coding.**Kindly if some one can help me get the video stream from camera. Thankyou**

Answer (score 1):

most likely because the camera is protected by password. to enable you to view the stream, please provide username and password to the camera you try to access.
for jpeg stream:

```
jpegSource.Login = "your username";
jpegSource.Password = "your password";
```

for mjpeg stream:

```
mjpegSource.Login = "your username"; 
mjpegSource.Password = "your password";
```